# Search in Firefox using Quicksilver

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, quicksilver

I am rather new to Mac OS X. I have been using quicksivler in order to open programs. I use Firefox a lot for searching in google, wikipedia, etc. I wonder if in Quicksilver or using another approach, one can do something for searching very easily like: type (quicksilver shortcut) + g + text (for searching in google, or + wk + text for wikipedia, etc

I heard about something similar for Firefox, some tool, but I do not remember the name now

thanks

Comment: yes, in firefo you can use ubiquity!

i wonder now how could i do this from QS and also send emails with thunerbird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a tool called Launchbar. I had to pay some money for it, but it was totally worth it. I've been using it for years now...and it does a lot more than just serve as launcher. It indexes several types of files including the Address Book app and iTunes, so you can access all of that from the keyboard too. The biggest thing Quicksilver has going for it is that it is free. But if you think about how much mileage you'll get out of Launchbar, the cost is worth it (it's about $37). Think about how much time and money you'd have to pay to code it yourself! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Web Searching with Quicksilver](http://guides.macrumors.com/Quicksilver#Web_Searching).  You can use that to set up all kinds of search handlers for Google, Wikipedia, IMDB, etc.